# O que é preciso para trabalhar na "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: debate

Sei lá me bateu essa curiosidade, gostaria de saber o que é necessário, eu realmente não sei se tenho capacidade, mas gostaria de saber o que é necessário, por exemplo:

- Saber falar inglês?
- Ter alguém quem indique?
- Tempo de experiencia profissional em outro lugar?
- Por onde começar?
- Com quem devo falar ou conversar acaso eu seja capacitado em alguma área?
- O Stack Overflow usa o https://stackoverflow.com/jobs pra divulgar ou procurar pessoas para trabalhar?

Comment: Acho que o primeiro quesito é "ter uma vaga" :p

Comment: @DiegoF mas é isso mesmo, como saber quando abrem vagas e pra que áreas, tipo tem uma nota no site oficial ou eles usam o Carreiras? (vou aproveitar e editar a pergunta)

Comment: Tem um link lá em baixo com o [trabalhe aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here)

Comment: @rray obrigado é isso mesmo!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cada [vaga aberta](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) tem uma lista de requerimentos própria. A única coisa implícita é o conhecimento de inglês, que normalmente não precisa ser avançado. Algumas vagas (vendas e marketing, principalmente) costumam exigir inglês fluente já que o trabalho vai ser justamente produzindo conteúdo ou se relacionando com clientes.

Indicações costumam ter um bom peso. Não são garantia de nada, mas ajudam.

No mais, fazemos o possível para avaliar cada candidato pelo seu potencial e características, não só pelo passado profissional ou experiências. E se você quiser uma vaga de programação, boa reputação nos SOs conta bastante.

Se tiver interesse em alguma das vagas abertas, lá mesmo tem um botão pra enviar seu currículo.
E nós sempre lemos todos que são enviados.

Comment: To dentro, hein

Answer (score 16):

Há algum tempo, antes de [migrar para a Austrália](http://luizricardo.org/2015/10/hello-australia/), apliquei-me para uma vaga através do [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) (que agora é o [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)).

Na época, recebi uma resposta de que eles haviam avaliado meu currículo e gostaram bastante, mas devido a restrições de orçamento deram preferência a candidatos locais.

Para quem não está a par, há algumas coisas importantes que devem ser consideradas ao se aplicar para uma vaga em outro país, tal como os Estados Unidos:

- Patrocinar um visto custa caro, muito caro. Não é só o que a empresa paga para o governo, mas envolve também custos de advogados e de manter pessoas só para cuidar do processo, ajudar com passagens, mudança, etc. Como o Stack Oveflow é uma empresa séria, caso eles fossem patrocinar sua mudança, provavelmente proveriam vários tipos de assistência, o que encarece muito a contratação.
- Mesmo que a empresa esteja disposta, ainda há uma loteria de vistos nos Estados Unidos que dão uns 50% de chance de você conseguir, portanto é arriscado para a empresa investir o dinheiro e ficar sem dinheiro e sem funcionário.
- O Stack Overflow não é uma empresa grande como Google, Microsoft, Amazon e Facebook. Dada a escala dessas empresas, eles já possuem departamentos inteiros só para cuidar dos imigrantes. Não que empresas menores não consigam levar pessoas para lá, mas eles vão precisar de mais motivos do que apenas um bom currículo para fazer isso.

Dito isto, se você está mesmo a fim, vá em frente. Não custa tentar.

Eu gostaria **muito** de ver as pessoas aqui do SOpt indo para as empresas *top*.

Comment: Pensei que tivesse alguma filial da Stack Overflow no Brasil, ou algo assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A filial aqui era o Gabe. :P

Comment: Outra coisa que dá para tentar é um trabalho remoto, mas sinceramente não são muitas empresas que tem estrutura para lidar com isso e, mesmo quando tem, geralmente você precisa passar um tempo lá para aprender com os outros e pegar o jeito.

Comment: Entendi kk, blz, a maneira é me virar no que tenho e com o tempo tentar evoluir, sei lá quero algo mais =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Faz muito bem. Se quiser saber mais sobre alguns detalhes do meu processo de emigração, sobre as entrevistas, leia meu artigo [Hello, Atlassian](http://luizricardo.org/2015/11/hello-atlassian/).

Comment: utluiz conheço pelo menos um caso de SO que trabalha remotamente. Acho que o @Gabe também chegou a fazer, mas sem certezas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mais da metade da SO trabalha remotamente. São muitos poucos casos de vagas que não podem ser remotas.

Comment: @Gabe ah não fazia ideia, pronto fica respondido :)

Comment: @utluiz Quando for fazer um artigo assim, me refiro ao do blog, não coloque tantas fotos "belas". Me sinto morando numa "lixeira", Brasil. rsrsr.
Mas excelente resposta e o mesmo se aplica ao artigo.

Comment: Só uma correção para os EUA: A *lottery* americana este ano (2016) foi de 75% de chance para H1-B, que é a modalidade de visto para a nossa profissão. As rodadas iniciam normalmente no dia 1o de abril e vão até o dia 1o de maio. Depois de passar, [o USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/) levanta toda a sua ficha para saber se você está apto a morar lá. A decisão final sai até setembro e a mudança efetiva ocorre em outubro. O visto profissional é de 3 anos e a cidadania pode ser obtida a partir do 2o ano morando lá.

Comment: Segunda coisa: pretendo relatar minhas experiências internacionais em breve, e novamente preciso agradecer ao Luiz Ricardo pelo apoio, que foi fundamental para que eu conseguisse.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Aguardarei ansiosamente pelo seu relato. :D